# Apollo Moon Landing

Tags: moonlanding

Can there be any truth to the rumour that the Apollo Moon landing in 1969 was staged ? I dismissed this rumour as being nonsense but today on the news I was surprised to hear that the head of the Police in Russia is calling for an investigation concerning this . Why does this rumour that it never happened persist even today ?

Comment: There are two distinct questions here: can there be any truth to the rumor (hint: no), and why does the rumor persist? In any case, this isn't an astronomy question; it might be a better fit for http://space.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Because of the internet and people with too much time on their hands...

Comment: I wouldn't transfer it to space.stackexchange.  The last time a question like that was raised people asked such questions should be ignored.

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate of the linked question because, despite the different title, the purpose is the same (to systematically attempt to investigate the possibility of a faked moon landing).

Answer (score 5):

No, there's not an ounce (gram?) of truth that the Apollo moon landings were faked.  The guys on Mythbusters did a good job of busting several of the so-called problems.  The light on the astronaut descending the ladder on the lunar lander was light reflected from the white space suit of the astronaut snapping the picture; the shadows that appear to indicate different light sources is actually a matter of topography; missing stars is because of basic photography (the foreground is so bright, the lens has to be stopped down to take the picture, thus not allowing the light from the stars to register on the film); and it is not actually possible to duplicate the 1/6th gravity by simply slowing down the playback speed.  Oh...and let's not forget the 100s of pounds of lunar rocks returned from several missions.  Here's a link to Mythbusters: http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/mythbusters-database/apollo-moon-landing-pictures-fake/

Comment: I am not doubting the authenticity of the Moon rocks but am curious as to what distinguishes it from an Earth rock ? What is it about a Moon rock  that tells you that it couldn't be from Earth ?

Comment: I went to the link you provided and the mirror that was left there ,from which lasers are bouncing off from the Earth , that is solid proof that they did indeed land.

Comment: Just a couple of sites I found:
http://www.spaceanswers.com/q-and-a/how-different-is-moon-rock-and-earth-rock/
http://meteorites.wustl.edu/lunar/howdoweknow.htm